# How To Get Data From Multiple Tables Without Duplications

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `tbl_Enquiry_Items` and `tbl_Estimation_Items` contains Enquiry and Estimations
Respectively

[image]

[image]

I am Fetching Data from `Tbl_Estimation_Items` Using Query

```
Select * from tbl_Estimation_Items Where Estimation_Id= 1
```

returning data Set of 5 Records. How can i get 6th row also Present in `tbl_Enquiry` as Well without duplication.

There is No Foreign key Between Them..
There is Another tables Which Contains `Enquiry_id` namely `Tbl_Estimation`
[image]

query i tried is

```
 
DECLare @EnquiryId int
Select @EnquiryId= Enquiry_Id from tbl_Estimation where  Estimation_Id= 1

Select   Estimation_Id, Rfx_Item_No , Material_No ,RTRIM( LTRIM(Description)) as Description , Quantity,Principal_Unit_Price, Total,Li_Discount_Percent,
Li_Discount_Amount ,Li_Principal_Total,Li_Principal_Currency,Li_Petromar_Unit_Price, Li_Petromar_Total,Li_Exchange_Currency,Li_Exchange_Rate,
Li_Petromar_Unit_Price_Fc,Li_Petromar_Total_Fc

into #temp from(
Select    a.Estimation_Id, a.Rfx_Item_No , a.Material_No ,a.Description , a.Quantity,a.Principal_Unit_Price, a.Total,a.Li_Discount_Percent,
a.Li_Discount_Amount ,a.Li_Principal_Total,a.Li_Principal_Currency,a.Li_Petromar_Unit_Price, a.Li_Petromar_Total,a.Li_Exchange_Currency,a.Li_Exchange_Rate,
a.Li_Petromar_Unit_Price_Fc,a.Li_Petromar_Total_Fc
from tbl_Estimation_Items a
left outer join tbl_Estimation b on a.Estimation_Id = b.Estimation_Id
left outer join tbl_Enquiry c on  b.Enquiry_Id = c.Enquiry_Id
where a.Estimation_Id= 1

Union

Select  1 as Estimation_Id, Rfx_Item_No ,  Material_No , Description , 
0.00 as Quantity, 0.00 as Principal_Unit_Price, 0.00 as Total, 0.00 as Li_Discount_Percent,
0.00 as Li_Discount_Amount ,0.00 as Li_Principal_Total, 0.00 as Li_Principal_Currency,0.00 as Li_Petromar_Unit_Price, 0.00 as Li_Petromar_Total,0.00 as Li_Exchange_Currency, 0.00 as Li_Exchange_Rate,
0.00 as Li_Petromar_Unit_Price_Fc,0.00 as Li_Petromar_Total_Fc

from

tbl_Enquiry_Items  where Enquiry_Id =@EnquiryId  
) tt

select *from #temp  

drop table #temp
```

but giving me following result set

[image]

Comment: What is your DBMS? SQL requests should always be tagged with the DBMS in question, so as to avoid answers that don't work for you.

Comment: SQL server rdbms

Comment: Okay, I've added that tag for you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  Tried But Not  getting what i expect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp), but if you select all the columns in `tbl_Estimation_Items`, it is needed to complete the values for the columns which are not present in `tbl_Enquiry_Items`. Or you can also just select the columns present in both tables. Here selecting all the columns:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  tbl_Estimation_Items WHERE Estimation_Id=1
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  Enquiry_Item_Id AS Estimation_Item_id,
  Estimation_Id,
  Rfx_Item_No,
  Material_No,
  Description,
  NULL as Quantity,
  NULL as Principal_Unit_Price
-- Keep adding the rest of the columns with null or assign a value
FROM
  tbl_Enquiry_Items WHERE Enquiry_Item_Id = 911
```

Comment: I need all the columns from tbl_estimation_items. Both tables dont have same columns. Can't do union..

Comment: And do you have the column values for the row you are trying to append (`Quantity`, `Principal_Unit_Price`, etc.) or do want to leave them in blank (null)?

Comment: I edited the above question.. you can check.. I want appended columns which are not there in tbl_estimation_items as 0.00.. above is the query I tried but it is returning me redundant data..

Comment: I have also edited my answer. Seeing your edit, I think you need to restrict the where statement to your target row. All the rows have `Enquiry_Id=1`

Comment: Yes.. but don't know what condition to put..as I need 5 row from tbl_estimation as these are estimated data.. now appending new added enquiry present in tbl_enquiry.. so I am expecting 6 rows returned ..

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear what you are trying to achieve.

There is an enquiry. An enquiry can have many estimations. The enquiry can cover more items than its estimations. Your database also allows the estimations to have items that are not part of the enquiry.

What you are probably looking for is an outer join. The following shows all rows from both item tables, whether they have a match in the other or not:

```
select *
from tbl_estimation est
join tbl_estimation_items esti on esti.estimation_id = est.estimation_id
full outer join tbl_enquiry_items enqi on enqi.enquiry_id = est.enquiry_i
                                      and enqi.rfx_item_no = esti.rfx_item_no
```

If you want the data for a particular estimation, then change

```
from tbl_estimation est
```

to

```
from (select * from tbl_estimation where estimation_id = 1) est
```

Comment: Not Getting Expected Result...I want  all the Records From Tbl_Estimation_Items. Those are estimated items...also i  want the item that are present  at the 6th rows in the tbl_Enquiry with additional column values containing as 0.00

tried Your Query modified it a BIt

select est.*
from (select * from tbl_estimation where estimation_id = 1) est
join tbl_estimation_items esti on esti.estimation_id = est.estimation_id
full outer join tbl_enquiry_items enqi on enqi.enquiry_id = est.Enquiry_Id  and enqi.rfx_item_no = esti.rfx_item_no  where enqi.Enquiry_Id=1

Comment: The `WHERE` clause at the end of your query turns the full outer join into a left outer join, thus not getting enquiry items without matching estimation items. Remove that `WHERE` clause and you should be fine. The `WHERE` clause inside the subquery already gets you the one estimation you want. (`est.*` only shows you the estimation rows multifold of course. Change this to a mere `*` or to the columns you actually want to see.)